# C# Linq take first item from list, cast error

Tags: c#, linq, casting

```
private List<Setting> _settings;
private Setting _setting;

_settings = _atlasService.GetSettings();
_setting = (Setting)_settings.Take(1);
```

I'm trying to set _setting as the first item in the list of _settings (there is only one record in the list)

On the last line of code I am getting this error:

> System.InvalidCastException
> HResult=0x80004002
> Message=Unable to cast object of type 'd__25`1[Atlas.Entities.Setting]' to type 'Atlas.Entities.Setting'.

Comment: Try FirstOrDefault() instead of Take(1)

Comment: `Take(n)` returns an *enumeration* `IEnumerable<T>`, not a value `T`

Comment: so, what is `'d__25`1` or where does it come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace the line `_setting = (Setting)_settings.Take(1);`

by

```
_setting = _settings.First();
```

the take method returns IEnumerable while you are casting to a just one Setting

Comment: You should explain your answer rather then just post a code dump.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to unboxing you can use:

`_settings.Take(1)`

if you want to convert different type:

`_settings.Take<yourAwesomeType>(1);`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, when you use either **.FirstOrDefault();** or **.First();** rather than *.Take(1);* it should work.

Answer (score 0):

[Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-7.0) returns IEnumerable.

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> Take<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count);
```

you are trying to cast `IEnumerable<Setting>` to `Setting` that is why you get the error.

since there is only one record in the list you should use `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`

```
_setting = _settings.FirstOrDefault();
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/first-firstordefault-single-singleordefault-in-c-sharp